# How to fix ng-invalid for nested template?

Tags: angular

I have a form which includes nested templates (child forms). Everything renders, but only the inputs in the parent form are valid. All the inputs in the child templates/forms are `ng-invalid`. Because they are invalid, the placeholders in the inputs are not showing, and instead an unsightly `[object Object]` shows where the placeholder should be.

Among other attempts:
1. To isolate the problem, I've eliminated validation in the nested form altogether, in which case the inputs in the child template do become `ng-valid` and their placeholders render properly, (but note the container `<app-sub-enroll-form>` remains `ng-invalid`). Because eliminating validation solves the `ng-invalid` problem for the `inputs`, this suggests that the problem lies somewhere in the validation process, but I can't see where it could be, as the process is virtually identical for the child template vs. the parent template (both use the identical `TemplateValidationService` Service). Somewhere in the child template the validation binding must be incorrect?
2. In the nested template, instead of setting the `form` to a newly created `FormGroup`, I tried adding the new controls to the existing `FormGroup` using `this.form.addControl`, but received console error that `_this.form` was undefined.
3. I've tried making the nested template a `<form>`, and also just a `<table>`, but this had no effect.

Parent Template

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="form">
  <h3>Form</h3>
  <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <ng-container *ngIf="topLevel(member[key]); else subTable">
        <td><input type="text" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" formControlName="{{key}}"/></td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #subTable>
        <app-sub-enroll-form [objEnroll]="member[key]" [formGroup]="form"></app-sub-enroll-form> 
      </ng-template>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Child Template

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <table style="margin-left: 5%;">
    <tr *ngFor="let key of objKeys">
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" formControlName="{{key}}"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<form>
```

Parent Component

```
export class EnrollFormComponent implements OnInit {
  formControls = {};
  form: FormGroup;
  @Input() member: Member = new Member("");
  memberKeys = Object.keys(this.member);

  constructor(private templateVal: TemplateValidationService ) {
//    console.log(this.memberKeys);
  }

ngOnInit() {
  this.memberKeys.forEach((key) => {
    let validators = [];
    this.templateVal.handleValidation(key, validators);
    this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.member[key], validators);
  })
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
  }
```

Child Component

```
export class SubEnrollFormComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() objEnroll : NameId | EmailData | PhoneData | AddressData;
objKeys: Array<any> = [];
@Input() form: FormGroup;
formControls = {};

constructor(private templateVal: TemplateValidationService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.objKeys = Object.keys(this.objEnroll);
    this.objKeys.forEach((key) => {
    let validators = [];
      this.templateVal.handleValidation(key, validators);
      this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.objEnroll[key], validators);
  })
  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
  }
}
```

Template Validation Service:

```
export class TemplateValidationService {

  constructor() { }

  handleValidation(key: string, validators: Array<any>) {

    validators.push(this.noSpecialChars);
  }

  noSpecialChars(c: FormControl) {
    let REGEXP = new RegExp(/[~`!@#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\';,/{}|\":<>\?()]/);
    return REGEXP.test(c.value) ? {
      validateEmail: {
        valid: false}
      } : null;
  }
}
```

I'm hoping to eliminate the `ng-invalid` issue (allowing placeholders to render properly) while keeping validation in the nested template. Many thanks in advance if any ideas!

Comment: I can't see from your code what is actually wrong, but i have a suggestion on how you could debug it properly: after `this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);` write `window['form'] = this.form` now you can access the form group from the browser console and inspect it. Look at the controls error property and see what is set. if the control is invalid an error should be set: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors

Comment: Many thanks. Where do I access the control error property? I looked in the Web Console under Inspector, Console, and Debugger, but didn't see where I can find the control error property. Tks!

Comment: `window['form'] = this.form` this creates a global variable for the form. So you can just type `form` in the console and then you can inspect the form controls

Comment: Tks. Strangely, errors is ` null` and status is `VALID`.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @x4rf41 for suggesting use of the debugger. Now that I have that tool at my disposal, I see that whereas I had thought I was passing a string to the validation handler in the child forms, I was actually passing an object, so the validation handler was correct in marking the input as `ng-invalid`. To fix this, I needed to add an extra dimension when creating the form control: `this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.objEnroll[key][1], validators)` (as opposed to the previous: `this.formControls[key] = new FormControl(this.objEnroll[key], validators)`. Embarrasing oversight, but now that I know how to use the debugger, hopefully in the future I'll catch these types of errors before posting to the community. Many thanks to everyone for their patience and help as I get up to speed on this stuff!